# Java : Override not needed methods inside classes - Update

Tags: java, interface, overriding, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

In my Project I have an abstract class that contains couple of abstract methods. Now multiple other classes extend that abstract class. Not all classes wants to override all the method of abstract class because that are not useful to them. How can I provide default implementation of those methods inside subclasses that aren't useful for the class?
Example-:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public void Action()
    {
     .....
     this.roar();
    } 

    public abstract void roar();

    public abstract void run();
}
```

Above is the abstract class that is going to have abstract methods that subclasses would implement.

```
public class Lion extends Animal
{
   @Override
   public void roar()
   {
      s.o.p("Lion roars");
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      s.o.p("Lion runs");
   }
}

public class Deer extends Animal
{
   @Override
   public void roar()
   {
      // Question : What should I do here?
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      s.o.p("Deer runs");
   }
}
```

EDIT-:

Thanks for suggestions, I understand the idea of having another class which can have method that aren't common ("roar" in this case).But My Project structure is a bit different and its kinda legacy code in which numerous subclasses extends from Animal class. Subclasses call a concrete method which in turn call abstract methods("roar" in this example, Please see updated Animal class with concrete method "Action").
Now as you suggested if I created another abstract class

```
public abstract RoaringAnimal extends Animal
{
    public abstract void roar();
}
```

This will solve one of the problem as I can now just extent RoaringAnimal instead if Animal but other classes which calls Animal.Action method, they won't find implementation of roar() inside Animal and javac will complain.

Comment: Have a base class that implements them?

Comment: As an aside, not all animals *run*. `move()` might be a more appropriate method name.

Comment: Check out composite patterns, they are a bit more tricky but they better suit applications like this I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a method that is appropriate for a subclass but not for a superclass, like the `roar` method here, then you may want to provide another abstract class that subclasses `Animal` but provides `roar`, say, `RoaringAnimal`.  The `roar()` method would no longer be declared in `Animal`, but in `RoaringAnimal`.

```
public abstract class RoaringAnimal extends Animal
{
    public abstract void roar();
}
```

Then you can have `Deer` extend `Animal`, not implementing `roar()`, but you can have `Lion` extend `RoaringAnimal`, implementing `roar()`.

Comment: This pattern is impractical for lots of objects with similar functionality. What about the `jump()` method that both lions and deers want but not the Dragon, who wants a `fly()` method. You'd end up with `RoaringJunpingAnimal`, `BarkingJumpingAnimal`, `BarkingRunningJumpingAnimal`, etc... I think that some mind of composite pattern would be better for this application. Of course that depends on how complicated his objects are or might likely become.

Comment: @Neilos As the complexity grows, then yes this becomes cumbersome.  For this example, it works sufficiently well.  Perhaps `RoaringAnimal` should be an interface that `Lion` implements, so combinations such as `RunningJumpingRoaringAnimal` are unnecessary.

Comment: I agree that it works for this example but it will very quickly become more trouble than it's worth because there are many combinations potentially, which is why I suggest a composite pattern; but this will come with a performance trade off so it's worth thinking about before commiting.

Comment: I went ahead and created another abstract class that going to have uncommon method. But there are other multiple number of subclasses that calls into Animal class and try to find declaration of that uncommon  method in Animal class. I really can't change those subclasses, because its kinda legacy code and I want my changes as passive as possible. [I've updated problem statement].

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally you do this:

```
   @Override
   public void roar()
   {
      throw throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }
```

This exception was created for this purpose actually

@rgettman answer is more suitable though! try not to use this method ;) But know that it exists, You can find some examples in core Java libs

Answer (score 1):

In such a case use an Adapter class. The adapter class will be a concrete class that extends your abstract class, but It will basically **implements its methods with nothing** or its methods implementation can **throw an exception that extends RuntimeException**.

There is a very nice example of this in Awt with the MouseAdapter class. [See the javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)

Here is an example:

```
class AnimalAdapter extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void roar() {

        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


    }

}
```

A Sheep class for exemple will extend AnimalAdapter, but will get a RuntimeException only if it tries to call roar.

```
class Sheep extends AnimalAdapter {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am a sheep I run, but I don't roar...");
    }

}
```

Exemple of such an exception

```
class NotImplementedException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One common solution are classes called Adapter classes. Those will implement all methods with a standard (or empty) implementation and you override the ones you want to change. The downside is, you don't know if the animal can do this or that.

Another possibility would be to split the abstract class into interfaces. Each set of methods that usually is combined together is put into one interface. The class will then implement the interfaces or not. This can end up in having feature interfaces for your animals (Roaring, Running, Crawling, ...), the animal implementation will then implement the interfaces it can fulfill. Dependencies between interfaces can be build by interface inheritance.

On Java8, there is the possibility to have default methods for interfaces, that could also be used for your classes. Instead of using the abstract baseclass, you use an interface with default methods.